Excel crashing when using named formula; dynamic chart data source
I have an Excel spreadsheet file that reliably crashes when trying to display a graph, from Excel Mac version 16.85 onwards; it's only when I downgrade to 16.84 that I can open and edit it.
I tracked the problem down to entering a formula of the format
=FileName.xlsx!namedFormula

The moment I press Enter, it displays the data in 16.84 but crashes in 16.85 and later.
I use this as a chart data source, because then I can decide what the range is inside the named formula; but the formula in this format entered as above reliably crashes the newer Excels even when just entered straight in a cell. It crashes the Excel iOS app as well. Until around May it worked fine for years, then 16.85 broke it.
Does anybody know if this is on the radar of Microsoft somewhere? Is this a tracked bug?
Alternatively, is there any other way of feeding a dynamic named range of data as a source for a chart?

You can give feedback to Microsoft about this problem:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11
